# java.lang.NullPointerException not showing where the error is

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

i'm working with a code they gave me to try to solve the errors, but until now, the Exception that is thrown only sends me to the line where the

```
log.error("Error saving data: " + e.toString());
```

is. i don't know how to find out the correct line, because the e.printStackTrace() doesn't output anything. The function is has this parts:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {...

try {...
} catch (Exception e) {

       e.printStackTrace();
       log.error("Error al almacenar los datos de usuario: " + e.toString());
    }
```

but in the middle i can't find any reference to an exception. how can i get the "catch" part to show me where the error is?

Comment: what does the stack trace say?

Comment: *"the e.printStackTrace() doesn't output anything."* I find that ***very*** hard to believe.

Comment: provide the Method code in which exception is occurring.

Comment: give the e.prontStackTrace() output? and your current servlet class name

Comment: you could also try just removing the catch, let it bubble further up while you debug. Also, catching Exception, rather than a more specific subtype, is a big code smell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to pass exceptions stackTrace to your logger. If you type e.printStackTrace() it puts stack trace to System.err

proper way is to write something,

log.error("your message",e);

and log4j will handle object e, and prints stackTrace in your logger.

Comment: thank you so much, it worked! it's fine to have people actually answering your questions and not pointing out "I find that very hard to believe" thanks thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're looking in the wrong place.

The stacktrace will be written in a file where the standard error goes.

You don't say which AS are you using ( if any ) but most of them have a stderr.out file of some sort.

Also, you can log the exception by using the logger as zaga250 says:

```
log.error("errrr", e );
```